# illegal reflective access operation -- Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've seen many questions around this topic but I really cant understand why I'm seeing this warning. I'm hoping someone can help educate me here.

From a code POV I've a pretty basic Spring Boot API which has a controller, service, Dal and DalImpl. The code flows pretty much like that and I seem to be getting the error when my controller calls my service layer. I cant figure out if I've done something wrong or not:

*Controller*

```
package com.mytest.dev.projects.controller;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import com.mytest.dev.projects.model.project.Project;
import com.mytest.dev.projects.service.project.ProjectService;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/projects")
@Api(tags = "Projects")
public class GetProjectsController {

    @Autowired
    ProjectService projectService;

      @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_read:projectinfo')")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Allows another Service (M2M) to retrieve a projects details")
    @GetMapping("/{projectId}/details")
    public Project m2mGetProjectDetails(Authentication authentication,
                                              @PathVariable String projectId) throws UnirestException {
        return projectService.getProjectDetailsById(projectId);
    }
}
```

*Service Layer*

```
package com.mytest.dev.projects.service.project;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import com.mytest.dev.projects.dal.project.ProjectDAL;
import com.mytest.dev.projects.dal.project.comments.ProjectCommentsDAL;
import com.mytest.dev.projects.dto.projects.UpdateProjectDto;
import com.mytest.dev.projects.exception.schema.*;
import com.mytest.dev.projects.model.likes.ProjectLikedByUsers;
import com.mytest.dev.projects.model.project.Project;
import com.mytest.dev.projects.service.m2m.RestTokenService;
import com.mytest.dev.projects.service.image.ImageStorageService;
import com.mytest.dev.projects.service.profiles.ProfileService;
import com.mytest.dev.projects.util.json.JsonNullableUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

@Service
public class ProjectService {

    @Autowired
    ProjectDAL projectDAL;

    @Autowired
    public ProjectService() {
    }

    public Project getProjectDetailsById(String projectId) {
        return projectDAL.findOneById(projectId); -->>>> This is where the warning is triggered
    }
}
```

And here is the warning message:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/Users/philipbannon/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.3.3/ea35bf756a880c699768ae0750e1244017d6ae84/spring-core-5.3.3.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

any insights would be most welcome.

Thank you all

Comment: Have you tried with a different version? This may be because of version compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to response @NirajJha which version are you talking about? Spring?

Comment: This may be because of spring. Are you using devtools or anything specific which requires cglib?

Comment: Nope, just using     id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.4.2"

Comment: Can you try with spring boot 2.3 and java version 8? Make sure you delete the target and take a fresh build.

Comment: Ah interesting you mention the version of Java. I'm using OpenJDK 14!